# getting getSignedRequest() using static HTML app?

Tags: php, facebook

I have an app called static HTML (https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/?ref=ts) installed on a page of mine..

I want to be able to access getSignedRequest() to pass data through the URL in facebook using app_data.. (I want to be able to pass an item id to activate a JS item in the iframe.. in essence allowing me to link to an expanded JS feature in the page)

The issue is that i am recieving NULL from getSignedRequest(); I am not sure if the app I am using (mentioned above : static HTML) is stopping the information from getting passed through to my iframe. 
If you are unfamiliar with this app, it allows you to put HTML/CSS/JS to embed an iframe.

On the hunch that it is the app that is stopping the propagation of the facebook data to my iframe, I have attempted to follow SEVERAL tutorials, both video and written that try to create a facebook iframe by creating a custom app.. none have worked, and i have not been successful in even adding a BASIC TAB to any of my pages..

I am about to give up on this facebook thing as every tutorial I have found has a completely different looking interface or set of instructions then what is ACTUALLY available on the facebook developers page..

Does anyone have a CLEAR UP-TO-DATE, non-facebook written walk-through, or atleast know if my use of the static HTML app is what is causing me to recieve null in my getSignedRequest()?

Here is my php code in the iframe i embed in the static HTML app, incase you think the error is in there somewhere.

```
require 'facebook.php';

//facebook signed app_data
$app_id = "xxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

// Get contents of signed request

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

Any help would be nice. I have wasted 2 nights on this crap.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but there are restrictions on accessing via javascript the page inside of an iframe.

Comment: I want to grab the variables from facebooks POST, then dump them into JS on my page embedded in the iFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.html files cannot accept HTTP POSTs unless the web-server is configured to accept this verb.  However, the only way to get at the post parameters is with server-side code and cannot be done clientside.

Comment: the pages I have embedded in the iFrame is php. I am thinking that the app that allows me to embed the iFrame is static HTML (as the name implied) and is thus stopping my iFrame from receiving the POST from facebook

Comment: Correct, most web-servers by default do not allow http POSTs to happen to htm or html pages.  You will need to run php (or other server-side scripting language) to capture and process the signed_request POST parameter.